# "A motion to adjourn is always in order." — Lazarus Long

Tags: expressions

Adjourn means **To suspend until a later stated time**.

But the statement

```
A motion **to suspend until a later stated time** is always in order.
```

does not makes sense.

What does it mean?.

Comment: Can you explain why it does not make sense to you? I suspect that you are not understanding the way one or more of the words are used, but I do not know which is or are giving you trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 'motion' means a proposed-thing-that-can-be-voted-upon, in a meeting.

A 'motion to adjourn' means the proposal that the meeting be adjourned.

If it's 'always in order' then that means it's always allowed.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert's_Rules_of_Order
or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliamentary_procedure

[motion](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/motion)

> A formal proposal put to a legislature or committee:

If it's in the context of a meeting then it's probably meant literally.

If it's outside the context of a meeting then it's probably a jocular (though perhaps rather pompous) way of saying, "yes, let's have a break".

For more discussion re Heinlein's usage see: http://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/a_motion_to_adjourn_is_always_in_order